# Changes to EBS snapshot affects original volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a snapshot of my `EBS` instance and then used it to create a volume.

After that, I connected the new volume to a separate `EC2` instance, I was expecting this new volume to work in isolation from the original volume but it seems to be writing the data on the original volume. Is there a way to do this on AWS?

Comment: *"it seems to be writing the data on the original volume."*  It isn't possible for writes to one volume to modify content on another volume, regardless of snapshot ancestry.  There must be another explanation.

Comment: Why do you think this is happening? Can you demonstrate it with a simple example such as `echo "foo" > /volume/file` on the new instance and then show that file on the old instance? If not, look for another cause.

Comment: I'm not sure is it possible that both the volumes point to the same `RDS` even? I'm not sure if that even makes sense; I don't know a lot about this so I'm confused

Comment: But I added some data from the ec2 server of one volume and then deleted it from the other volume; it got deleted for the original too

Comment: Occam's razor would say that it's more likely that you were logged into the wrong instance. To get an answer you're going to need to show the exact steps that you took. As your question is written you're asserting that something happened that should not be possible, and are not providing any proof that it actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Snapshots are a copy of "differences" from previous snapshot. So, you will always have history. Based on [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-creating-snapshot.html):

> A point-in-time snapshot of an EBS volume, can be used as a baseline for new volumes or for data backup. If you make periodic snapshots of a volume, the snapshots are incremental—only the blocks on the device that have changed after your last snapshot are saved in the new snapshot. Even though snapshots are saved incrementally, the snapshot deletion process is designed so that you need to retain only the most recent snapshot in order to restore the entire volume.

Comment: I want the history but I want to know if I can manipulate the data on the snapshot without affecting the original volume

Comment: "snapshot" is sort of backup. You can't directly operate on it. You need to use some hacky ways like create a volume from snapshot, delete whatever you want to and create an AMI/Snapshot again.

Comment: To clarify, I restored my snapshot as a volume. Then I attached that volume to my EC2 instance